# Zero order Tensor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

One of the definition of tensor is that it should be invariant under transformation. Thus a tensor of order zero is a scalar should be invariant under transformation. For a tensor component $v^{\mu}$ the inner product $v^{\mu}v_{\mu}$ is a tensor of rank zero and should be invariant under Lorentz transformation.But,
$$v'^{\mu}v'_{\mu}={\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha}{\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\beta}v^{\beta}v_{\alpha}$$
${\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha}{\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\beta} $ not equal to ${\delta_{\beta}}^{\alpha}$, which implies $v'^{\mu}v'_{\mu}$ not equal to $v^{\mu}v_{\mu}$. This shows that $v^{\mu}v_{\mu}$ is not invariant under transformation(not a tensor). Can anybody suggest where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. Its typing mistake.

Comment: I want to know wheather the inner product of two tensors which contract to a zero order tensor is invariant under transformation.

Comment: Yes, it is. To see how, first you have to be careful about index placement. You cannot just write $\Lambda^\alpha_\mu$ because ${\Lambda^\alpha}_\mu$ is not the same thing as ${\Lambda_\mu}^\alpha$. Second, you need to write down the defining relation for $\Lambda$ to be a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Sorry I'm unaware of the mathjax symbols. I edited the question. I think the question is valid now.

Comment: OK. Do you know what relation $\Lambda$ has to satisfy to be a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: $\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda =\eta$

Comment: Well, thank you @G. Smith I got my answer by substituting the above equation.

Comment: Right. Work that out in index notation and you should find that ${\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha}{\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\beta} $ *is* equal to ${\delta_{\beta}}^{\alpha}$ because the mixed-index ${\eta^\mu}_\nu$ is ${\delta^\mu}_\nu$.